# Using Geocorder result in other function in VUe

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

i try to use the result of Geocode Lag Long, but i can't use out of the function. How can i use the result in other function in Vue?

Why i can't use "this.markerCoordinates" in other functions?

```
getLocation : function (address){
  const element = document.getElementById(this.mapName);
  var local;
  // geocoder API (pega o endereço)
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(address);

  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function (results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            // I WANT USE THIS IN OHTER FUNCTION
           this.markerCoordinates = [{"latitude" :latitude , "longitude" : longitude}]

           callback( this.markerCoordinates[0])
        }
        var mapCentre = this.markerCoordinates[0]

        var options = {
          zoom : 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.latitude , mapCentre.longitude)
        }
        this.options = options;

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

      this.markerCoordinates.forEach((coord) => {
        const position = new google.maps.LatLng(coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
          position,
          map: this.map
        });
      });    

  });     



},
```

in other functions is return undefined

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a `data` element for your coordinates in your component, see [here for an example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering): `data() {return { markerCoordinates: undefined } }`
2. In your `getLocation` function, you need a closure that points to the enclosing Vue instance , like this `let vm = this`. See [here, e.g.](https://riptutorial.com/vue-js/example/28955/right--use-a-closure-to-capture--this-)
3. In the callback, use this variable to access the data element: `vm.markerCoordinates = [{"latitude" :latitude , "longitude" : longitude}]`
4. Access the it in the template simply by using `markerCoordinates` and in other methods of your component with `this.markerCoordinates`